# ExpressionChangedAfterItHasBeenCheckedError: Expression has changed after it was checked with Float

Tags: angular

```
ERROR Error: ExpressionChangedAfterItHasBeenCheckedError: Expression has changed after it was checked. Previous value: 'width: 93.7598541666%'. Current value: 'width: 93.7604513889%'.
    at viewDebugError (core.js:17871)
    at expressionChangedAfterItHasBeenCheckedError (core.js:17859)
    at checkBindingNoChanges (core.js:18059)
    at checkNoChangesNodeInline (core.js:27637)
    at checkNoChangesNode (core.js:27624)
    at debugCheckNoChangesNode (core.js:28228)
    at debugCheckDirectivesFn (core.js:28156)
    at Object.eval [as updateDirectives] (AppComponent.html:101)
    at Object.debugUpdateDirectives [as updateDirectives] (core.js:28145)
    at checkNoChangesView (core.js:27523)
```

I get the above error but the code still continue

```html
<div [ngStyle]="{
                  'margin-left':task.getFrontMargin(dayStart, hourResolution)*100+'%',
                  'width':task.getWidthPercent(dayStart, hourResolution)*100+'%'
                }" 
     class="flag" [ngClass]="task.type">
</div>
```

Comment: what is task.type? and where are you setting it?

Comment: `task.getWidthPercent(dayStart, hourResolution)` causes the problem. its value changes within change detection cycle. which means either `task` `dayStart` `hourResolution` gets changed somewhere in your code. so please share your full ts and html code.

Comment: Yes, I have getter in a task called by getWidthPercent which return new Date() everytime. Is that the issue? How to solve that ?

Answer (score 0):

This kind of error occurs when we work in angular in developer mode because in developer mode the angular performs the check twice to confirm whether the property has the same value as that in the previous check.

Now, as your width is changing depending upon the getWidthPercent() so that changes the width in between the angular checks. This prompts an error.

To remove it you can set the width in ngOnInit() method using the setTimeOut() method
In this way - 
Get the div selected using the local reference in the typescript and inside ngOnInit method use

```
    @ViewChild('localReference') private element: ElementRef;

    ngOnInit() {
        setTimeOut(()=> {
            element.nativeElement.style.width = task.getWidthPercent(dayStart, 
            hourResolution)*100
        });
    }
```